# How to optimization this MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have two table the structure are given bellow, those table have lots of data but can't change the table stucture

Table "postsale"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `postsale` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `season` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `sale_no` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `auction_date` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `season_time` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `lot_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `invoice_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `origin` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `tea_type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `sub_tea_type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `mark` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `no_of_packages` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `gross_wt` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `net_wt` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `auction_valuation` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `lsp_sp` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `package_type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `package_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `auctioneer` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `auction_price` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `buyer` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `broker_code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `csv` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `session` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29623 ;
```

and Table finalesale

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `finalsale` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `season` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `sale_no` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `auction_date` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `season_time` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `lot_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `invoice_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `origin` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `tea_type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `sub_tea_type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `mark` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `no_of_packages` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `gross_wt` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `net_wt` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `auction_valuation` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `lsp_sp` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `package_type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `package_no` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `auctioneer` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `auction_price` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `buyer` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `broker_code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `csv` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `session` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=41365 ;
```

based on the above two table, the execution time of this query is huge so, I need to optimized the following query

```
UPDATE `finalsale`,`postsale` 
SET 
  `finalsale`.`auction_price`=`postsale`.`auction_price`,
  `finalsale`.`csv`=`postsale`.`csv`,
  `finalsale`.`session`=`postsale`.`session` 
WHERE `finalsale`.`lot_no`=`postsale`.`lot_no` 
      AND `finalsale`.`group_id`=`postsale`.`group_id` 
      AND `finalsale`.`group_id`='201217CLGuwahatiJT'
```

Please help

Comment: omg, redo that schema at once, check MySQL docs

Comment: You won't be able to optimize the query much more. If it is slow, you will need to consider indexing some columns.  The `lot_no` cols for example are `VARCHAR()`. They may benefit from indexes on both tables.  `group_id` is also `VARCHAR()` and perhaps should be indexed.

Comment: @Michael, LOOK at the schema, you can't do much worse, short of perhaps choosing text() for storage type ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes Yes, obviously. But major schema overhauls aren't always possible. If you have suggestions for the OP on how to improve it, I suggest you actually _offer them_ instead of just criticizing it.

Comment: see first comment, the OP needs to do some homework prior to optimizing the query -- learning about storage types is essential, renders the most optimized queries pointless.

Comment: My eyes My eyes. Seriously now that table definition needs some work.

Comment: How many rows in final_sale will match that particular group_id?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a serious performance improvement from choosing the correct data types in your table definition.

There are several columns which appear to contain only numerical information, which is better stored in some `int` column.

Furthermore there are columns for some dates like `auction_date` that should be transformed to a date - datatype.

Also think about the length of your varchar columns. Most of the time you wont need the 255 characters there.

Have a close look at the [Mysql Docu for datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html).

If you have performance problems afterwards you may think about creating indexes on some columns. But I strongly recommend thinking about this just *AFTER* you reworked your table definitions!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is not possible for you to improve on the schema (which as has been mentioned in the OP comments is rather... bloated), you probably would get a significant performance boost **for this specific query** by adding an index on `lot_no` and `group_id` on each of the tables.

Since you're using InnoDB, you might consider using a foreign key constraint (this also covers indexes), although it depends on the semantics & lifecycle of the tables, which I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following indexes:

Single column:

```
finalsale: (`group_id`)
```

Multi-column:

```
postsale: (`group_id, lot_no`)
```

These indexes allow MySQL to first limit the result set by applying the constant in the WHERE clause to the finalsale table, and then, with that minimal result set, perform a join to the postsale table, fully utilizing the index.